# How can I find which questions have been closed as the duplicate of a given question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to see which questions have been closed as duplicates of a given question -- a sort of "backlinks" search?

For instance, let's say I have a question A. Questions B and C are both closed as duplicates of A. It's obviously easy to go from B or C to A, but can I go from A to B and C?

Comment: They should appear in the "linked" section on the right side of the page.

Comment: @user000001 That seems to be a superset. That is, some of the questions in the "linked" section aren't closed-as-duplicate. I think any time someone mentions a question from another question, it's a link (but I'm not sure). Still, that may be the best we have.

Comment: You might want to use SEDE as the postlinks table hold the linktype for just duplicate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238850/158100. If I'm not mistaken postlink isn't updated if the duplicate vote is retracted or if the question is reopened.

Comment: @rene That did it! Thanks. I can post a self-answer unless you'd like the glory. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can query the `postlinks` table using SEDE:

```
select top 100
  postid as [Post Link]
, creationdate as [Closed On]
from postlinks
where linktypeid = 3 -- duplicate
AND relatedPostid = <question that something's a dupe of>
ORDER BY creationdate DESC
```

For instance, to get dupes of "[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)", question 513832, you would [run the query using 513832 as the parameter](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/497326/duplicate-of-a-given-question).

Credit to @rene for pointing the way.

Comment: @OrangeDog http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325720/how-can-i-find-which-questions-have-been-closed-as-the-duplicate-of-a-given-ques?cb=1#comment354810_325720

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a query that does this that's a little bit more robust than the original: [Duplicates for [Post]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1430005/)

It returns all posts linked as a duplicate for the given post, with posted date and linked/ dupe-close date listed for each.

The dupe target post is listed first, and all subsequent posts are listed thereafter, sorted by post date (with the most recent first).

Like the other query, it requires the target post's ID to pull this information.

Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT                                  -- Pull target post
  'Target:' AS [#####],
  CONCAT('site://q/', pwd.Id, '|', CASE -- Link post, show '[deleted]' if post is deleted
    WHEN pwd.DeletionDate IS NULL
    THEN pwd.Title
    ELSE '[deleted]'
    END
  ) AS [Post],
  pwd.CreationDate AS [Date Posted],
  NULL AS [Date Linked]
FROM PostsWithDeleted pwd
WHERE pwd.Id = ##OriginalPostId:int##
UNION ALL
SELECT                                  -- Pull all dupe posts using PostLinks table
  '' AS [#####],
  CONCAT('site://q/', pl.PostId, '|', CASE 
    WHEN pwd.DeletionDate IS NULL
    THEN pwd.Title
    ELSE '[deleted]'
    END
  ) AS [Post],
  pwd.CreationDate AS [Date Posted],
  pl.CreationDate AS [Date Linked]
FROM PostLinks pl
JOIN PostsWithDeleted pwd ON pwd.Id = pl.PostId
WHERE RelatedPostId = ##OriginalPostId:int##
  AND LinkTypeId = 3 -- Link type for Duplicates
ORDER BY [#####] DESC, [Date Posted] DESC
```

<sub>Bonus, related query: [100 Most Duplicated Posts on [Site]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1430008/)</sub>