# Can I know that my question is used as a referral/source for duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

You all know how duplicates work:

A person asks a question Q1, which gets an answer A1.
Later on, another person asks a very similar question Q2, and he or she gets informed that Q2 is a duplicate of Q1. I just had a look at such a Q1, and I did not see any marks that Q1 was used as a source for duplicates. Does such a mark exist?

The reason I'm asking this:
I already had the situation that I asked a question and I answered that question myself, and afterwards, I'm not satisfied with that question/answer and as I'm the only one who has written both question and answer, I seem no harm in deleting that question with that answer.
Now imagine that this question is marked as a source for a duplicate, then that duplicate question would not have an answer anymore.

Is there a protection against this case and if yes, is there a reason not to show this as some mark on the duplicated question?

(As I don't know if this feature exists or not, I've decided to mark this question as a "discussion")

Comment: "You can't delete your own *question* ... if it [has at least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)"

Comment: There's a list of "linked" questions on the right sidebar (example: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?lq=1)), though they also include any posts linked on the comments and answers, not necessarily questions closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: [How can I find which questions have been closed as the duplicate of a given question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325720/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark: Thanks a lot for your duplicate, I particularly love the reference to http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query for querying this website.